# How to query mongodb with DBRef

Tags: reference, mongodb, dbref

suppose I have the following datastructure:

```
var user = {_id: 'foo', age: 35};
var post = {_id: '...', author: {$ref: user, $id: 'foo'},...};
```

How can I query all posts which references user[foo]? I tried the following but not work:

```
db.post.find('author._id': 'foo');
var u = db.user.find({_id: 'foo'});
db.post.find('author': u);
```

neither can I find the answer from the official document and google!

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind from the MongoDB API documentation: "Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead"

Comment: @lcedDante, that's true. I start to use manual references across my projects years agao and never come back to dbref. had to say it's much easier to manage.

Comment: db.post.find('author.$id': 'foo') has missing {} in query , and $ before _id.
this would be: db.post.find({'author.$id': 'foo'})

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Got it:

```
db.post.find({'author.$id': 'foo'})
```

Comment: Does anyone idea how to accomplish the same using MongoEngine?

Comment: This is the best I've been able to come up with:
`Post.objects(__raw__={'author.$id':'foo'})`

Comment: I had to use db.post.find({'author.$id': ObjectId('foo')}) to get this to work.

Comment: Yes usually it is `ObjectId('....')`, it could also be `NumberLong(...)`, and could also be `'foo'`, it really depends on which type you are using for the id column

Comment: Somebody with this issue with morphia? We have a workaround here but it is not so nice.

Comment: @Joqus in Morphia I've tested this method:    Author authorQuery = dataSource.find(Author.class, "name", "author-name").get(); 
     
   List<Disc> discs = dataSource.find(Disc.class).disableValidation().field("author.$id").equal(authorQuery.getId()).asList();  where Disc contains a reference to Author though a DBRef

Answer (score 20):

This `db.post.find('author.$id': 'foo')` has missing the `{}`, so the correct sentence is:

```
db.post.find({'author.$id': 'foo'})
```

Also this can be achieved with:

```
db.post.find({'author': DBRef("user", ObjectId('foo'))})
```

But is more compact and practical the first way.

Comment: Thankx Mrdev, I've fixed the missing `{}` error in the answer

Comment: how can we see the content of the referenced object

Comment: The second option worked best for me as it allowed me to specify the name of the child/parent collection (polymorphism)

Answer (score 11):

You can use the .$id reference but it will ignore any indexes on those fields. 
I would suggest ignoring that method unless you are querying it directly via the terminal or want to look up something quickly. In using large collections you will want to index the field and query it using the below method.

If you want to use an index query using the following:

```
db.post.find('author' : { "$ref" : 'user', "$id" : 'foo' , "$db" :'database_name' })
```

If foo is an object id

```
db.post.find('author' : { "$ref" : 'user', "$id" : ObjectId('foo') , "$db" :'database_name' })
```

You can create an index on author by

```
db.post.ensureIndex( {'author' : 1 } );
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a Java solution to this then if you are using [mongojack](http://mongojack.org) its really easy:

```
collection.find(DBQuery.is("user", new DBRef(user.getId(), User.class)));
```

Where collection is a JacksonDBCollection.

Answer (score 1):

In mongoengine you should just use the instance of the referenced object. It should have the ID set.
Suppose the author is the Author document instance. So using this:

```
Post.objects(author__eq=author)
```

you can go through all posts of this author.
Post.author should be defined as ReferenceField

Answer (score -1):

Using Mongo 2.4.1 version

This is how you do it on command line for OLA collection where `@DBRef dbrefName`

`db.OLA.find({"dbrefName.someFieldValue" : "Personal"});`

Exact query

`db.OLA.find({"dbrefName.$id" : ObjectId("1234")});`

Comment: dbrefName is just object with $db, $id, $ref keys, not some alias to another collection

Comment: Updated with exact query to reference object. Let me know if it still does not work.